# HTML shrink td to fit image size

Tags: html, css

I am laying out a website with a table, and the logo goes in the top row of the table. The logo is a mostly transparent image with a green background, and it is in a table with a red background. However, the table cell is not shrinking to fit the image vertically and so it is showing some of the background red below the image when I don't want it to. I have tried setting the `margin` and `padding` all to 0, setting `cell-spacing` and `cell-padding` to 0, and removing borders, but none of it has worked.

My browser's page inspector tool shows that the `td` element is responsible for extending the height of the cell, not the `tr` or `table`

What am I missing? I feel like it is something really simple.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles2.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <table id="layoutTable" >
      <tr>
        <td class="layoutTabletd">
          <img id="logoImage" src="res/logobar2.png"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper
{
  width:              1000px;
  margin-left:        auto;
  margin-right:       auto;
}
#layoutTable
{
  background-color:   #FF0000;
  margin:             0px;
  padding:            0px;
  border-collapse:    collapse;
}
#layoutTable tr td.layoutTabletd
{
  border:             1px solid black;
  padding:            0px;
  margin:             0px;
}
#logoImage
{
  background-color:   #00FF00;
  margin-left:        auto;
  margin-right:       auto;
  margin-top:         0px;
  margin-bottom:      0px;
  padding:            0px;
}
```

Result:
[image: result]

Comment: Is this rendered in Strict mode, Almost-strict or Quirks mode?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel No idea. How do I check? I am using Safari 8.0.8

Comment: Great question... Try setting `display:block` on the image. If it does nothing, then it may be in almost-strict mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved: http://jsfiddle.net/r0801v5v/

```
#layoutTable
{
  line-height:0;
  background-color:   #FF0000;
  margin:             0px;
  padding:            0px;
  border-collapse:    collapse;
}
```

Notice the added line-height:0; - I am not exactly sure why this happens but I've seen it before. Hope I helped.